# Const compiler/runtime

Tags: programming-languages, constants

How are treated constants in various languages/compilers? They take up space in RAM in runtime or are replaced with their values ​​at compile time?

Comment: What language? What compiler? What type of constants?

Comment: Please be more specific in your questions, currently this is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compiler is free to go either way. The typical way to handle this is to use scalars directly while keeping larger objects like arrays in memory.

In addition, if you build an embedded system, they typically go into read-only memory like flash rather than RAM.